# chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener blocks chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, listener

Adding an onMessage-listener prevents my onInstalled-listener from triggering. Why?

This is my code:

---

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "BUGTESTER",
  "description": "Hmmmmm...",
  "version": "0.1",

  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

---

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  alert("onInstalled");
});

//Adding this line breaks the onInstalled-thingy
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {});
```

Comment: It that a typo, or did you just not close the `addListener`? And for your information, it is [`chrome.runtime.onMessage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage) now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem, just a typo, was missing a ) and a ;.
Isn't there any kind of syntax checking when loading extensions? =S

Comment: There is. It would have told you in the background page's console about the error.

Comment: Where do I find that console? ^^

Comment: Under extensions, click on the `Inspect views` link.

Comment: @Moberg See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029 for opening the background page's console.